# iOS: Replacing modal ViewController with UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I present a modal ViewController using `presentViewController`. Now I want to flip this modal view using `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal` so from within the presented ViewController I call:

```
flipsideView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:flipsideView animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

The animation looks fine. But when I dismiss the `flipsideView` first modal view is still visible.

Is there a way to dismiss both modal views at once using the `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical`. Or is it possible to replace the first modal view with the flipsideView using the flip-animation?

Thanks!

Comment: so you have 2 views, and you what to dismiss both like popToRootViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go back to the first controller like this, from a button in the flipsideView:

```
-(IBAction)goBackToFirst:(id)sender {
    self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```